# Error: Main method not found in class through the Page Factory Test (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, main-method, page-factory

Building the framework on `Java/Eclipse/Selenium WebDr/Page` Factory to create my tests. But when running the test, it gives an error that says:

> "Error: Main method not found in class, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args) "

Even if I add the main method, the test still won't be run. Please, help with how the main method should be inserted into my test, or any other suggestions. The code example is below:

Test example:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and share the code that you are having this error with. And also the code where you tried adding the main method.

Comment: Are you using JUnit or TestNG?  How are you attempting to run the project?

Comment: Thanks for your help. My mistake was in missing the  @AfterClass

  public void endTest() {
    
    
   }
   
   }